# Querying URLs on ports other than 80 with urlfetch() on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, port, urlfetch

Is querying for URLs present on ports other than 80 allowed with urlfetch()

I would like to get data from a server on a non-standard port -

http://example.com:8000/WebService?input=a

Ideal example would be web services hosted on non-standard ports.

Can i do this somehow with appengine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [app engine documentatio](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html)n says that you can use Python's [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to make your requests which will automatically use Google's urlfetch service. Using `urllib2` you can indicate the port number in the hostname.

```
import urllib2
conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com:80')
print conn.read()
```

I haven't tested it on GAE, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Edit:

From the [GAE documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html):

> The URL to be fetched can use any port number in the following ranges: 80-90, 440-450, 1024-65535. If the port is not mentioned in the URL, the port is implied by the scheme: http://... is port 80, https://... is port 443.

This implies that the port can be specified in the url while using the standard urlfetch API.